# How to apply double animation on a control from another xaml?

Tags: wpf, animation, button, mvvm, prism

I have a button that should cause fade-in animation on some other controls(Studio, Animation, Record...) which are located in ANOTHER xaml:

```
<Button x:Name ="MainButton" Grid.Row="87" Grid.Column="150" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Command="{Binding AutoClickFadeinButtonCommand}">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Studio" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Animation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="0.3" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Record" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="0.3" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Info" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="info_content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

How to reference these controls in my current xaml? Just to mention that I use mvvm, and I would like not to reference button control inside ViewModel class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an event inside your ViewModel and attach an event trigger to your XAML (e.g. `ControlStoryboardAction`) that starts the animation as soon as the event has been triggered.

**Edit:**

You could put something like that inside your VM:

```
public event EventHandler AnimationCalled;

protected virtual void OnAnimationCalled()
{
    AnimationCalled?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

As soon as anything will call `OnAnimationCalled` (any method that is triggered by your button or a command) the event will be raised.

You can subscribe to this event inside XAML by using a trigger (the `SourceObject` has to be the VM containing your event) in combination with the `ControlStoryboardAction`:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger SourceObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" EventName="AnimationCalled">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

---

**Edit 2: Complete Example**
The `MainViewModel`:

```
using System;
namespace StoryboardTriggerExample
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {

        //Only needed to have a target for our CallMethodAction
        //In real world it´d be easier to make the call to OnAnimationCalled(); via command
        public void CallAnimation()
        {
            OnAnimationCalled();
        }

        public event EventHandler AnimationCalled;

        protected virtual void OnAnimationCalled()
        {
            AnimationCalled?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

An `UserControl` that will contain our Storyboard:

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StoryboardTriggerExample"
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" x:Class="StoryboardTriggerExample.UserControlContainingStoryboard"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="#FF101085"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="30"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="30"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="100"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="100"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle1">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="#FF6BFF63"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="AnimationCalled" SourceObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
            <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle1" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="30" Stroke="Black" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" d:LayoutOverrides="LeftPosition, RightPosition, TopPosition, BottomPosition"/>
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</StackPanel>
```

And our `MainWindow`:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StoryboardTriggerExample"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" x:Class="StoryboardTriggerExample.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" MethodName="CallAnimation"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
    <local:UserControlContainingStoryboard/>
</StackPanel>
```

Should look like this:

[image: Startup]

Should move animated via storyboard to this, by clicking the button:
[image: final]

You can download the solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/Nebelkraehe/StoryboardTriggerExample)

Comment: Thank you, but can you please give me some more hint?

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check if it helps. Otherwise I`ll post a complete example.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really lost. If you can, please post complete example.

Comment: Added a complete example and a GitHub link.

Comment: I actually have a problem with this part: "<StackPanel>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="AnimationCalled" SourceObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}">
            <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</StackPanel>"

Comment: because I must use Grid in my design, and Grid does not allow me to put "<i:Interaction.Triggers>" tag directly in it.

Comment: Grid will also let you put Triggers on it. I updated my GitHub-Repo. Make sure you added the correct namespace for i and ei inside your solution `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"` Those are the Expression dll´s Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll and Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.dll

Comment: Thanks. I have these namespaces: "             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"

Comment: Happens often if ReSharper is turned on. Glad it works now.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but it actually didn't work. There is some kind of conflict between dll's. WPF automatically includes System.Windows.Interactivity, but for the other, I must install Blend through NuGet. When I do that, and include Microsot.Expression.Interactions, then the other one freaks out

Comment: System.Windows.Interactivity should work since it´s part of the Blend SDK. Which .NET Version do you use? Have you downloaded und tried my GitHub-Example? Take a look inside `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.5\Libraries` there should be System.Windows.Interactivity.dll and Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll. If you import both, it should work.

Comment: I haven't tried your example yet, but I believe it works. I use 4.5 version. No compilaton error anymore, but I get run time error: " Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Interactions, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified." I points to this line: <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>  But I am sure that I have this assembly reference included in my project.

Comment: And yes, they are both present in the file path that you have mentioned

Comment: I´d delete both dll from your References, to avoid any mismatch regarding versions and then go to Package Manager Console and type `Install-Package Expression.Blend.Sdk` and `Install-Package MicrosoftExpressionInteractions` to reinstall both into your solution again.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. By the way, I just tried yours, and it worked. Although there was a syntax error at "AnimationCalled?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);" so I changed it to "AnimationCalled.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);"

Comment: Glad to hear. BTW if you´re changing from `AnimationCalled?.Invoke...` to `AnimationCalled.Invoke...` make sure to query if `AnimationCalled != null` before the call to avoid a possible `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Ok, will do. I just re-installed them through the console, and they work fine. Not only that, my own application works exactly the way I wanted it. Thanks a lot! You really saved me!

Comment: Perfect! Glad to hear.